# custom top menu navigation in sharepoint

Tags: navigation, custom, branding, top-link-bar, pages

I have a question regarding a top navigation that will look something like this:

```
Home | Staff | IT | Organization
```

With subitems on f.x. IT like this:

```
Manuals
Protocols
```

In a dropdown menu like suckerfish
There are one main entry page with three office pages
In a tree-view it will look like this:

```
Main
  - Office 1
    - Staff
    - IT
      - Manuals
      - Protocols
    - Organization
  - Office 2
    - Staff
    - IT
      - Manuals
      - Protocols
    - Organization
  - Office 3
    - Staff
    - IT
      - Manuals
      - Protocols
    - Organization
```

How can I achieve this specific request? Will I need to create subpages and subpages on subpages for the dropdowns or is there another way like a custom navigation provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using This Custom Feature you can create Custom Top Navigation Feature

**Requirement**: Had to customize the Top navigation with bunch of provided internal/external links as part of a branding project.

**Solution**: Designed a feature to programmatically add links to top navigation bar. when activated, feature will add bunch of links to the top navigation bar.

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/feature-for-customizing-top-navigation.html#ixzz2MjWG4usN

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/feature-for-customizing-top-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use a wiki library to create the individual pages, then use your own javascript/css/html menu to whatever styling youd like, as a matter of fact, i'm doing the ssame thing in a project I'm working on now where I deploy my own navigation, just to navigate through the wiki's. One could set it up as a collapsible/hideable breadcrumb trail.

Also, the wiki library has an out of the box view that may provide something similar to what you're asking for. Check it out, mess around with them.

You'll have to add the code to each page, but you probably already know that.

Creating sub-sites under subsites is bad practice (just in my opinion, as the site's hierarchy and the URL's of sites become way too long and its harder to search for what you want.)